# Event attributes as prerequisits

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-science

We are developing a system for event management. Events have attributes as prerequisits, e.g. to find the right trainer for a Judo event, that fulfills the prerequisits of the event, e.g. Judo, a trainer with **at least an orange belt**, with driving license for **at least a minibus**, and appropriate certificates. Does any one know any framework or an idea, how to hold the prerequisite (data structure) in the database and what algorithm to use, so that it would be easy to check and find the apropriate trainer for an event ? The user should be able also to define new attributes with value to be used as a prerequisits. So events and trainers should have attributes to be used as prerequisits.

Any hint/help would be very welcomed.

Thanks in advance,

Dani

Comment: Not clear: Is it a question about a database (relational? graph?) or about a data structure?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. It is not an SQL question, it is more to have an algorithm to match between events with prerequisites (attributes), and resources fulfilling the prerequisits (attributes).The attributes can be of any data type. User should get a list of matching resources to select. The matching process should take also conditions in account, e.g greater than, equal,... So I'm looking for a way to define the attributes, to make the matching process possible. The user can also define new attributes, and assign them to events or resources.
I hope this make things some what clearer.

Comment: e.g. an event/course for JUDO, a trainer is required having at least an orange belt, at least 20 years old, with driving license for e.g. at least a minibus... what makes things complex is the fact is, that there are conditions to be taken in account for the matching (at least,...), so some attributes needs to have a numeric value, some just string,...